# Nested ngRepeat limitTo not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently having a problem with ng-repeat  and limiting the amount of elements being displayed in my view.  I'm wondering if it has to do with being a nested loop.  Here is the code:

```
<li style="cursor:pointer; margin:8px;" class="span3" ng-repeat="psp in preSplitPrompts" ng-click="selectRelatedSplitPanels($index)">

    <div ng-class="$first ? 'panelBackground' : 'altPanelBackground'" class="thumbnail splitPanel">
        <h3>{{ (psp.promptname) ? psp.promptname : "No Name From API" }}</h3>
        <hr>
        <h2 ng-repeat="postsplit in psp.postSplit | limitTo: 1">{{ postsplit.metrics.preSplitTotalCount ? postsplit.metrics.preSplitTotalCount : 0 }}</h2>
        <p>Visits</p>
    </div>

</li>
```

I've tried limiting the list item by doing limitTo:1 and that works fine.  It's only when trying to limit the postsplit.  Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

This code works:

```
<li style="cursor:pointer; margin:8px;" class="span3" ng-repeat="psp in preSplitPrompts | limitTo: 1" ng-click="selectRelatedSplitPanels($index)">

    <div ng-class="$first ? 'panelBackground' : 'altPanelBackground'" class="thumbnail splitPanel">
        <h3>{{ (psp.promptname) ? psp.promptname : "No Name From API" }}</h3>
        <hr>
        <h2 ng-repeat="postsplit in psp.postSplit">{{ postsplit.metrics.preSplitTotalCount ? postsplit.metrics.preSplitTotalCount : 0 }}</h2>
        <p>Visits</p>
    </div>

</li>
```

Here is the data object:

[image: preSplitPrompts data object]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ng-class="{$first ? 'panelBackground' : 'altPanelBackground'}"
```